# Javascript variables undefined when inside object function and paused on debugger

Tags: javascript, object, scope, closures

Update: Just tidying this post up because the issue seemed to change slightly. It seems to be an issue with **Chrome** dev tools not working correctly when paused on the breakpoint.

**EDIT: Updated the first example, it seems to be an issue with chromes debug tools. It seems that if you don't include a console.log statement within `otherFunc` and pause on the debugger the variables are undefined. They should be and it works correctly in firefox.**

```js
var a = (function(window, document, undefined) {
    var View = {
        initialize: function() {
            // this prints
            console.log('started the view');
        },
    };
    var Controller = {
        start: function() {
            View.initialize();
            this.otherFunc();
        },
        otherFunc: function() {
            // try logging View and Controller in console
            debugger;
            // View and Controller are undefined

            // using console.log works eg console.log(View) does not give error.
        },
    }
    Controller.start();
})(window, document);
```

As opposed to the following, if you include a console log statement you are able to access the variable from chromes dev tools.

```js
var a = (function(window, document, undefined) {
    var View = {
        initialize: function() {
            // this prints
            console.log('started the view');
        },
    };
    var Controller = {
        start: function() {
            View.initialize();
            this.otherFunc();
        },
        otherFunc: function() {
            // We can now access View from the console while paused.
            debugger;
            console.log(View); // seems to fix the issue
        },
    }
    Controller.start();
})(window, document);
```

Comment: I've just run your code and there were no errors. could you paste the stack trace of the error?

Comment: nope, you're wrong where you say `// these both throw errors`

Comment: I've taken the liberty of changing your code to an executable snippet - run it yourself, you'll see it works - perhaps you've removed too much from the **actual code** to demonstrate your issue (I'm guessing there's callbacks involved in the **actual code**

Comment: Try adding a debugger statement just inside `otherFunc` and remove the console logs and running it. I'm getting a referenceError sometimes, but then if I do it with the console logs it does actually work you're correct. Right now I'm removing and adding in the console log and that seems to make it work correctly, not work?

Comment: as "otherFunc" only accesses View and Controller in a console.log, I can't see how removing those console.log statements would cause the code to throw an error "sometimes"

Comment: Oh!!! are you trying to use View and Controller in the CONSOLE during debugging? well, that wont work - **edit:** correction, that DOES work (at least in firefox)

Comment: It works in firefox for me as well, can you try normal chrome?

Comment: what the heck is "normal chrome", you mean Chrome? ... doesn't work in Chrome. Chrome debugging has always been poor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136658/discussion-between-d-young-and-jaromanda-x).

Comment: no need for a chat ... doesn't work in Chrome developer console during debugging ... use a better debugger, or don't concern yourself with variables you can't access in the console ... your page doesn't run in the console